# How can you share data between multiple android devices using the same Unity application?

Tags: android, get, unity-game-engine, send

I would like to get and send data to android devices that runs the same Unity application. Most data that will be sent will be booleans and locations (longitudes and latitudes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand your question, but if what you want is to make your Unity3d app/game communicate with other mobile phones using the same app/game you can either do it with: the internet, bluetooth, NFC. The easier solution is communicating through the internet which you'd have two solutions:

- Create a server that will receive the data you want to send and which will "pair" the devices you want to send. Each device will send the data to the server and the server will then send the data back to the other devices.
- Make some P2P solution(peer 2 peer solution) which is probabaly what you want. In this solution the devices will connect directly to each other and send the data.

Luckily Unity3D has a networking engine that can help you with that. Look at:
https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/multiplayer-networking
https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UNetOverview.html

And here is a simple tutorial on how to use the Unity solution https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/multiplayer-networking/introduction-simple-multiplayer-example